# Qt QTreeView/QHeaderView add minimum-width depending on text header section

Tags: qt, resize, qtreeview, qheaderview

I have a `QTreeView` widget and I want to add a `minimum-width`. The minimum-width will be:
`minimum-width = headerSectionText_width + sortArrow_width`.

I also want to keep the resize interactive, so the user can make it bigger, but not smaller than the minimum-width.

[image]

Based on the picture, don't allow any column to be smaller than `title_width + sortarrow_width`, but as big as the user decides.

Is there any way to achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: minimumSectionSize is generic for all sections. I want the minimum to be different for each section, depending on the text width of each section

Comment: I want to be interactive (as big as they want it to be), but having a minimum width... If I set it to fix, they won't be able to resize it.

Comment: You're right sorry, I didn't find any API way to do it, maybe a custom delegate could force that but I only see a preferred size with the sizeHint (no minimum size).